# Using K-means clustering with predefined seeds in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I need and example showing how to use K-means clustering in MATLAB but using some prespecified datapoints as the initial seeds.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IDX = kmeans(X,k,'start',seeds)
```

will run [K-means](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.htmlhttp://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.html) with predefined datapoints `seeds` (such as `k` rows of `X`, but you can choose any seeds as long as it's a `k`-by-p array, where p is the number of columns of `X`) as initial seeds. Note that if you specify `seeds`, you don't need to specify `k` (pass `[]` instead). `kmeans` will infer from the number of rows of `seeds` how many clusters you want.

By default, `kmeans` chooses `k` randomly picked rows of `X` as seeds.

Comment: but what would be in this "seeds", an index to a datapoint or the datapoint itself?

Comment: @Hossein: The datapoint itself. For example, if `k` is 2, you could use the first two rows of the data `X`, i.e. the first two data points, as seeds.